# I do not know how I change `cls` unconsciously

Tags: spacing

I use 'cls' of a conference. Two adjacent pages, one flushes right, the other flushes left. I mean `the blank space of right` is smaller than `the blank space of left` in one page. Then, the following page is inverse. But I add my content in the `submission.tex`. Then the left and right space of every page are `equal`.  I do not know what's the problem? I only use this [`cls`](http://ist.ac.at/oagm2014/author-information/).

```
\documentclass[review]{OAGM}
%% For the accepted, final version, set this to the correct value:
%%\OAGMarXiv{0000.0000}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{ulem}
 \usepackage{float} % fix the table
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsopn}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{breqn} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{achemso} 
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle}
\begin{filecontents*}{\klkl.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: UTF8

@INPROCEEDINGS{conf/icml/AvronKKS12,
  author = {Avron, Haim and Kale, Satyen and Kasiviswanathan, Shiva Prasad and
    Sindhwani, Vikas},
  title = {Efficient and Practical Stochastic Subgradient Descent for Nuclear
    Norm Regularization.},
  booktitle = {ICML},
  year = {2012},
  publisher = {icml.cc / Omnipress},
  added-at = {2013-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2b9ed7719ec246e3629d4b41b5515c7f9/dblp},
  crossref = {conf/icml/2012},
  ee = {http://icml.cc/discuss/2012/617.html},
  interhash = {afa43f2081a8e76fd4ceeca426a7dc66},
  intrahash = {b9ed7719ec246e3629d4b41b5515c7f9},
  keywords = {dblp},
  timestamp = {2013-01-25T00:00:00.000+0100},
  url = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/icml/icml2012.html#AvronKKS12}
}


\end{filecontents*}






%\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Equation \eqref{#1}}}
\let\originaleqref=\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}{Equation~\originaleqref}

\newcommand{\dataset}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\fracpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial  #2}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\newarg}{arg} 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}                  % for absolute value
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}           % for average
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}            % for norm
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}            % for {}
\newcommand{\sbra}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}            % for []
\newcommand{\lbra}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}            % for ()
\newcommand{\reffig}[1]{Figure \ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\d}[2]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d} #1}{\mathrm{d} #2}}       % for derivatives
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}            % for partial derivatives
\let\underdot=\d                             % rename builtin command \d{} to \underdot{}
\title{Margin?}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Today is 3/14/2014.
 \end{abstract}
\newpage
Here is a new page.
\bibliography{\klkl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem. Also, if possible, provide a link to the `.cls` you are using for the conference.

Comment: When I compile `submission.tex` from the [link you provided](http://ist.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/events_pages/oagm2014/oagm-submission.zip), I obtain [the expected output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0E7vJ.png) in terms of the layout with unequal margins. If you're getting something different, then you must be something *different*. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @ Yes, they should be unequal. Ok, I will write one. Thank you.

Comment: Please follow the link provided by Werner and take a few minutes to really prepare an MWE.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't be loading `geometry` (nor `fncychap`, `setspace`, `fancyhdr` and `import`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bunch of packages you're loading don't make sense with this class.

The problem you see is due to `geometry`: the class wants a certain layout and you shouldn't change it.

Remove also

```
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

that don't agree with the class.

Comment: They want eight pages with *their* layout.

Comment: Thank you. I know it. DO not need to check the question anymore. I think the answer it right. I try it again. The resultant pdf is right although there is error.